# Responsive slider - width pushing the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

So i've found this slider and i've been trying to adapt it to responsiveness. It should occupy 100% width of the screen, image always centred so I can add specific break points depending on media queries.

The problem is that when I resize the screen, the slides keep 100% of the screen size but "half" slide. Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGKvJr

HTML

```
   <div id="oob_sli">
  <div class="o_i">

   <a href="#" class="control_prev"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="o_g">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">  </a>
    </div>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: red;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  height: 100%;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  height: 100%;

background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#oob_sli {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 630px;
  height:270px;
}

#oob_sli ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  height: 270px;
  list-style: none;
}

#oob_sli ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 270px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 270px;
}

.o_i {
  width:130px;
  height:270px;
  position:absolute;
  float:left;
  z-index:1;
  left:0px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 280% );
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 280% );
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 280% );
  opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
.o_g {
  width:130px;
  height:270px;
  position:absolute;
  float:right;
  right:0px;
  z-index:1;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 280% );
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 280% );
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 280% );
  opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;

}
.control_next{
    width:130px;
    height:33px;
    margin-left:30px;
    top:43%;
    bottom:50%;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inverticons-fill-vol-3/32/arrow_left_back_previous-128.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:50px;
  background-size:30px 30px;
    }
.control_prev {
    width:130px;
    height:33px;
    margin-left:-55px;
    top:43%;
    bottom:50%;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/inverticons-fill-vol-3/32/arrow_left_back_previous-128.png) no-repeat;

    background-position:70px;
  background-size:20px 20px;
    }
#oob_sli:hover .o_i{


  opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;

}
#oob_sli:hover .o_g{

  opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
```

}

SCRIPT

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   function do_slide(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      moveRight();
    }, 4000);
  }
  do_slide();
   $('ul li').hover(function(){
       clearInterval(interval);
     });
      $('ul li').mouseleave(function(){
       do_slide();
     });

    var slideCount = $('#oob_sli ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#oob_sli ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#oob_sli ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;


    $('#oob_sli').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#oob_sli ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth            });

    $('#oob_sli ul li:last-child').prependTo('#oob_sli ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#oob_sli ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 700, function () {
            $('#oob_sli ul li:last-child').prependTo('#oob_sli ul');
            $('#oob_sli ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#oob_sli ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 700, function () {
            $('#oob_sli ul li:first-child').appendTo('#oob_sli ul');
            $('#oob_sli ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

If you resize the screen from right to left , for exemple, you will understand what I'm saying. I need it to always occupy the full width of the screen.

How should it be implemented?